# Parse the text into a column from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a project and one of the source filed value provided in a single row like below and I need to convert this source field value into rows depending upon the number of dates provided in the string.

| Case_Number | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| INC0112233 | 09/12/2022 02:30:04 - System Incident automatically closed after 14 days in the Resolved state. 18/11/2022 16:53:30 -X_User Awaiting response from customer 10/11/2022 14:23:10 - Y_User good afternoon, I've looked into this further and checked the logs 10/11/2022 12:46:40 - X_User let the customer know 10/11/2022 11:55:55 - X_User will be reviewing this later today |

Now I want this single row data into 5 rows like below

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INC0112233 | 09/12/2022 02:30:04 | System Incident automatically closed after 14 days in the Resolved state |
| INC0112233 | 10/11/2022 12:46:40 | X_User Awaiting response from customer |
| INC0112233 | 10/11/2022 11:55:55 | Y_User good afternoon, I've looked into this further and checked the logs |
| INC0112233 | 10/11/2022 10:25:26 | X_User let the customer know |
| INC0112233 | 10/11/2022 11:55:55 | X_User will be reviewing this later today |

I tried using `STRING_SPLIT` and various combinations of `PATINDEX` And `CHARINDEX`, but none of them giving me a result that I'm looking for. I tried searching google but no luck.

Any idea how I can achieve the desired result?

Comment: How is the data provided? Is it another table or a txt file?

Comment: Why not simply use `LEFT` and `RIGHT`? You know the length of the datetime value will always be 19 chars, seems like a pretty easy job to me

Comment: It's in a table, a unique key also available like say Case_Number

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the source data as `ddl` and `dml` statements (check out sql-server tag info if you're not sure what I mean)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Sorry, If I was not clear enough in my original post, the whole text provided in a single column and it required to split into multiple rows based on the date.

Comment: It would still help us to help you if we had ready-to-use sample data.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: What character separates the values is it a space or a newline? Looks like it might be always two spaces? Your attempts would help also.

Comment: @Charlieface - There is a "-" separator after each date value and a new line separator after each comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` to split the column into rows, then use `LEFT` and `SUBSTRING` to get the separate parts

```sql
SELECT
  c.Case_Number,
  CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(s.value, 19), 103),
  LTRIM(SUBSTRING(s.value, 22, LEN(s.value)))
FROM Cases c
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(c.Comment, CHAR(10)) s;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/GqAQy9HK)